# Actualizar un div ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Quiero llegar a hacer un `div` que recarge solo cuando halla una modificacion en la base de datos actualmente tengo esto asi, si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria es para un sistema de turnos que estoy haciendo :

```
 <?php


require_once("../../db/db.php"); 

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  `turnos` ORDER by `turno` desc limit 1" ); 
$row = $result->fetch_row(); 

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      swal({ title: "siguiente turno : '.$row[0].'", 
      text: "Se envio correctamente", 
      type: "success",
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 2000
    });
     </script>'; 

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el ajax:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
setInterval(function() {
  $('#turnos').load('./ajax/turnos.php');// Selector de la div y el fichero a refrescar
}, 1000); // Temporizador que ejecuta el refresco cada 1 segundos
</script>
```

div :

```
<div id="turnos"></div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, debes tener un error en el archivo web.php, si puedes agregalo a la pregunta

Comment: Me alegro! saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `turnos` ORDER by `turno` desc limit 1" );



    $row = $result->fetch_row(); 

    echo json_encode(['turno'=>$row[0]]);

    var turno_actual=0;

    function desplegarAlerta() {
   // despliego la alerta desde el front
   swal({
    title: "siguiente turno : " + turno_actual,
    text: "Se envio correctamente",
    icon: "success",
    button: true
  });
}

function refrescaTurno() {



      $.ajax({
     url: "./ajax/turnos.php",
     dataType:'json' // parseo la respuesta como objeto
   }).then(function(response) {
      // sólo lo ejecutas si el turno cambió
      if(response.turno != turno_actual) {
         turno_actual=response.turno;
         desplegarAlerta();
      }
      window.setTimeout(refrescaTurno,2000);
   });

}

refrescaTurno();
```